# Hover on image scale hidden behind other div tag

Tags: html, css, image, hover, mousehover

I managed to make the hover on image but the image seems like hidden behind the cards. How can I make it visible infront of the cards?

here the screenshot

[image: the image seems some part of the image was hidden behind the cards as I've circled in the screenshot]

and this is my css

```
  .zoom {
    transition: transform .2s;
  }
  .zoom:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(4); 
  }
```

What can I add in my css to make it visible infront of the cards?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to move the image in front of the cards;

```css
.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(4);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give z-index higher than right section cards to your pc section